# Prove a functions inverse is differentiable on a domain if it is always increasing or decreasing

Tags: calculus

My calculus textbook gave this theorem without a formal proof:

> theorem Suppose that the domain of a function f is an open interval on which $f' (x) > 0$ or on which $f '(x) < 0$. Then $f$ is one-to-one, $f^{−1} (x)$ is differentiable at all values of $x$ in the range of $f$, and the derivative of $f^{−1} (x)$ is given by Formula (2). $\dfrac{dx}{dy}= \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{dy}{dx}}$
>
> Anton, Howard. Calculus, 10th Edition (Page 428). Wiley Higher Ed. Kindle Edition.

For my class I do not need to know the proof but an understanding of what would a formal proof would look like would be helpful.

Furthermore is there a name to this proof.

I conceptually understand this proof as an increasing or decreasing function's inverse would be a function. Therefore, since the function is differentiable and it's inverse is also a function then the inverse would be differentiable. Correct me if I am wrong or if my wording makes no sense.

Comment: You want the assumption that $f'(x) > 0$ or $f'(x)<0$. The sign of $f$ is irrelevant.

Comment: At least if $f'$ has constant sign all the time, then you can use the mean value theorem to conclude that $f$ is either completely increasing or completely decreasing. To show that $f^{-1}$ is differentiable, literally write down the difference quotient for $f^{-1}$ (the quantity whose limit is the derivative) and use a change of variable to suitably modify it into a difference quotient of $f$, which definitely exists.

Comment: The formula for the derivative is fairly easy from the definition of derivative provided you know that the inverse is continuous. To prove continuity you have to observe that it is also monotonic; assuming that it has a jump discontinuity at some point you have to get a contradiction.

Answer (score -1):

The fact that the inverse is a function doesn't mean it's differentiable.  For example, $f(x) = x^3$ is an increasing differentiable function on $(-\infty, \infty)$, its inverse is a function, but the inverse is not differentiable at $0$.  You need the added information that $f'$ is never $0$.  See [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem).